# Get multiple values from table, then echo them

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a PHP script that is trying to get multiple values from a table and store them in an array. I am querying the table for "camtronius2" and I want to get the associated values for "rank" and "guild" EACH time "camtronius2" is found.

[Here Is My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITRpz.png)

So far from the code below I am able to get one of the values "BRNT", but there is another value that is not being shown. I should be seeing an output of "BRNT" and "BAMM" for guilds. I havent started trying to get the "rank" part yet...

Could someone help me? See code below:

```
$invcheckquery = "SELECT _to, _from, rank, guild FROM guildinvite WHERE _to ='" . $username . "';"; 
$invcheck = mysqli_query($con, $invcheckquery) or die("error code : invite already sent!"); 
$invinfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($invcheck);

$check_num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($invcheck);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($invcheck, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
echo ($row['guild']);  // The number
}
```

Comment: Include them in the loop as you did for the only one you're echoing.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I did, but it still only echo's one row. I need it to echo the row each time "camtronius2" is found

Comment: so what's not working exactly? You have a username as a variable in the `WHERE` clause, which looks fine to me; I'm not grasping what you're asking, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You have two fetches, one outside the loop, and one inside, I am guessing you want something more like this:

```
$invcheckquery = "SELECT _to, _from, rank, guild FROM guildinvite WHERE _to ='" . 
$username . "';"; 
$invcheck = mysqli_query($con, $invcheckquery) or die("error code : invite already sent!"); 
while ($invinfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($invcheck)) {
{
      echo ($row['guild']);  // The number
}
```

Not exactly sure, why you are getting the number of rows, when you aren't in your snippet using it.

Comment: this isnt exactly what I was looking for, and there are some errors in it. I need to get both the rows that "camtronius2" is located in. Then i need to store their data in an array

Comment: The only thing that is different from my code and your code is, you are placing the first row into $invinfo.  Then you would enter the loop and print the next row.  That is what was happening to your other row.

Comment: Forgot, I also got rid of the number of rows, I am guessing you were using that to figure out how many rows you got back.

Answer (score -1):

Just try this:

```
$invcheckquery = "SELECT * FROM guildinvite WHERE _to='$userName'";
```

I have checked this on my local machine and found it working.

```
 $invcheck = mysqli_query($con, $invcheckquery);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($invcheck, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo ($row['guild'] . '----');  // The number
 }
```

Output:

```
BRNT----BAMM----
```

Comment: I think he wanted us to go further like put them in an array for him as well, not to just figure out what was wrong with his code.